# SQL schema many to many relationships

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am working on a school project and am running into some trouble with my understanding of building SQL schema ER diagrams.

I have 4 entities; a customer table in a one to many relationship with my order table, an order table with a one to many relationship with my line item table, a line item table that is currently in a one to many relationship with a burger table.

The problem I'm running into is that my line item table has a composite primary key of order id, burger id and I believe that line item->burger should be in a many to many relationship because one or more line items can be associated with one or more burger and vice-a-versa but my understanding is that you do not want any many to many relationships in a normalized tabled. Are my assumptions that it's supposed to be many to many correct and why am I allowed to have a many to many relationship?

For reference my table is currently in 3NF form

Ignoring modality and assuming it's always a minimum of one, if my Burger entity has a one to many relationship with line item then I'll have the following

[image]

Which means that one burger has one or more line items associated with it, however my thought process tells me that this isn't the only case, and in fact one line item can have more than one burger but from everything im reading this is not the case. The composite keys have me really confused, and I do see why it may be in a burger->line item one->many due to the burger count field which pertains to only a single burger type (it holds the value of how many burgers are in the line item).

What I believe it *should* look like:
[image]

Edit:
**Please ignore the customer and order tables, they were only included to provide a full view and I did notice that I forgot to include foreign keys just now.**

Comment: I understand this is for school, that's why I actively pointed it out. But I'm not trying to get you to do my homework, I'm trying to figure out what exactly is allowed in a normalized table. So please if anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Many to Many relationships are generally something to be avoided, but don't necessarily have anything to do with normalization. Look into associative entities (commonly called junction tables as well) for how M:M are usually resolved.

Comment: It's entities not tables that are in relationship/association with each other. It is relationships/associations that have cardinality X:Y:etc. After we get an ER design each entity/box /diamond & each relationship gives a table & each participation/line gives a FK. Also NFs have nothing to do with ER. There are a lot of presentations/methods that claim to be ER but are not; eg they use "relationship" to mean FK & more or less move directly to tables without clearly addressing Es & Rs. Please tell us your textbook name & edition. Read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: I just updated my post with more information and a couple visual cues to help get this question rolling.

Comment: Alright so I understand after reading more into it that normalizations don't pertain to ER diagrams but I still need help with the above. I have created all the working SQL code, and everything else I just don't understand how to draw these diagrams and the relationship between the line item and burger, maybe I am just overthinking it.

Comment: You just added diagrams. They are pseudo-ER. Eg a M:M line represents a *relationship/association* so becomes a table & should be between entities. Anyway please justify design aspects by *referencing your textbook*. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. Never give a diagram without a legend/key. So here precede each diagram by adequate text--give each entity & relationship's name & attributes & lines between.

Comment: I don't have a textbook everything is given by the professor and I believe that I just talked myself into confusion, sorry.

Comment: I doubt that you have not been given references. Anyway the problem here is you aren't really following a specific procedure, so you need to find out what it is, and we can't tell you because there are many variations & many notions--an answer would be rewriting a textbook & even then it wouldn't be *your* textbook. ([The wiki article on ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) is sort of ok re there being variations. Key is, follow the procedure showing us your work/justification until you are unsure then ask. PS Search my answers re ER & database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that line item->burger should be in a many to many

Why would a single line item be related to multiple burgers?  It wouldn't.  An order has many line items.  Each line item refers to a single burger.  The top diagram is correct.

Note that normally you sell things other than burgers, and you have line items that don't refer to a product, like taxes, discounts, etc.  So often the PK of the items table is just (OrderId,OrderItemId), and the ProductID is a non-key attribute.

Comment: I think I just ran myself in circles because initially that's what I had and it made sense but I convinced myself otherwise. I'm sure this question will be downvoted into oblivion now because it was so simple and stupid but you still helped me out so thank you for the direct answer.